# WSO2 Message Broker - hierarchical Topics Publisher

Tags: wso2

Good Day.

We have a option to subscribe topics & sub Topics messages in wso2 MB by configuring [topic.#]. then we can consume all the messages both topic & sub topic.

In the same way , is there any option to publish the messages to both topics & sub topics?. I mean if publish the messages to parent topic, then it should broadcast to all the sub topics.
Is there any option available in wso2 MB ?

please assist.

Thanks,
vinoth

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no such implementation for publish messages with wildcard in JMS spec even. Because topic name consider as routing key and when you publish messages. You have to be specific on routing key. Below documentation will be helpful to understand hierarchical topic in WSO2 MB.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/MB300/Managing+Hierarchical+Topics
https://docs.wso2.com/display/MB300/Creating+Hierarchical+Topic+Subscriptions

Comment: Hi, I hope we can do the wildcard topic publisher in activeMQ and also wso2 MB is also developed on  top of active MQ. so I taught this behavior also available in WSO2 MB.

Comment: For clarification, WSO2 MB is built on top of Apache Qpid.